# Compiling c and c++ module

Tags: c++, c, linker, freeswitch

Let's say i'm working on an already existing freeswitch module (https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch). These are loaded dynamically.

I've created modules in the past, this is not really my problem. My problem comes from an already existing module, let's call it my_module. In this module I'm adding a new functionality where i need to decrypt a jwt token parameter encrypted in AES.

The existing module main file, the file loaded by the main freeSWITCH loader is in C., let's say something like this:

```
#include <switch.h>
#include <switch_json.h>
#include <switch_stun.h>
#include <jwt.h>

#include "token_crypto.h" <-- This is my addition

...
<some stuff goes here>
```

at some point i do this:

```
 plaintext_len = token_decrypt( *token_encoded, plaintext );
```

my token_crypto.h is

```
SWITCH_BEGIN_EXTERN_C

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/buffer.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>


void handleErrors(unsigned char *ciphertext);
int gcm_decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len,
            unsigned char *aad, int aad_len,
            unsigned char *tag,
            unsigned char *key,
            unsigned char *iv, int iv_len,
            unsigned char *plaintext);
int token_decrypt( const char token_encoded, unsigned char *plaintext );


SWITCH_END_EXTERN_C
```

And then the actual implementation in token_crypto.cpp

I added the requirement to compile token_crypto in the Makefile.am like this:

```
mod_mymodule_la_SOURCES  = \
    base64url.cpp \
    token_crypto.cpp \
    mod_mymodule.c
```

The code then compiles ok, but when i try to load it i'm getting:

```
**/usr/local/freeswitch/mod/mod_mymodule.so: undefined symbol: token_decrypt**
```

I know the linker can't find the compiled references, but i just can't figure out how to link it all up...

A sample Makefile can be found here https://github.com/signalwire/freeswitch/blob/master/src/mod/applications/mod_skel/Makefile.am

Maybe i should point out there are other cpp source code filed in use on that .c file.

I know that by using "extern c" the compiler doesn't mangle the function name... but what does that mean in terms of actually using the function in the c source file?

comments like "google this", "google that", are not helpful. I obviously did all that before coming here, so...

Comment: your "C" source file token_crypto.cpp has cpp extension so linker uses mangled names

Comment: google ' extern "C"'

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently it's not enough with "extern c" the include header file.. for some reason that's what i remembered.

If one doesn't "extern c" also the actual cpp implementation, then the functions will be mangled. Adding the "extern C" to the implementation worked for me.

Thanks everyone anyway.